# Zebra RW 420 not printing everything as it should

Tags: android, bluetooth

I use android bluetooth printing and have this cpcl file:

```
! U 
JOURNAL 
SETFF 50 2
SPEED 3
CHAR-SET LATIN9
PRINT 
! U1 PW 720 
! U1 LMARGIN 30
! U1 SETLF 10 
! U1 SETLP Ari08pt.cpf 0 14 


! U1 SETLP Ari16Bpt.cpf 0 30 
     Details

! U1 SETLP Ari10Bpt.cpf 0 14
Test: ! U1 SETLP Ari08pt.cpf 0 14
 $routineTitle$ 

...

Service Data:
! U1 SETLP Ari08pt.cpf 0 4
$seData:{ 
    Time: $it.timeString$
}$
```

It prints ok, until it gets to loop (seData), then it stops for a little time and then prints half of each row. Any ideas? Is that printer problem, code problem?

I noticed that sometimes it also everything prints ok, but most of time not good.

Comment: why it has [android] tag

Comment: maybe it has someting to do with it. don't know. just that you know